# is there any programing language independent cryptography algorithms?

Tags: c++, asp.net, qt, encryption, cryptography

I am developing a licensing block for a project, the **QT desktop program** creates a product ID and the user must enter this ID in an **asp.net** web site to produce an Activation Key, this activation key contains some information that needed to activating the product, and must be decrypted in **QT desktop program**.
What I need is a cryptography library or just one algorithm to can encrypt information in **ASP.net** and Decrypt it in **QT(c++)** or vice verse.

Can any one please guide me?

Comment: Language independent as in programming language? Sure, crypto algorithms are language agnostic.

Comment: If you use standard crypto this will be no problem. The real problem is using crypto correctly. If you don't, somebody will publish a keygen after looking at your product for 5 mins.

Comment: [Keyczar](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) is available natively for java, python, C++, [C#](http://jbtule.github.io/keyczar-dotnet/), and [Go](https://github.com/dgryski/dkeyczar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those algorithms aren't oriented for any specific language. Just get a some crypto library in ASP, some crypto library in c++, and simply encrypt in ASP and decrypt in c++...

As long as libraries are following correctly algorithm's specification, it won't be any problem.